# Правильно ли указана высота и ширина элементов в вёрстке?

Tags: css, flexbox

Насколько корректно указана ширина и высота элементов?

https://codepen.io/Krutov/pen/ZrdQeE

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 20px;
    color: blue;
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.wraper{
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: bisque;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid gold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left{
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 180px;
}

.center{
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.right{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: right;
}

.footer{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.clearfix:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.text_style{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main class="wraper">

<header class="header text_style">header</header>

    <content class="clearfix">

<aside class="left text_style">left</aside>

<aside class="center text_style">center</aside>

<aside class="right text_style">right</aside>

    </content>

<footer class="footer text_style">footer</footer>

</main>
```

Comment: Вероятно, нет...

Comment: Что необходимо исправить?

Comment: А откуда я знаю?

Comment: И с чего возникла идея `footer c header-ом` сунуть в `main`?

Comment: А что касается ширины и высоты, это сугубо твое личное дело... кому знать как не тебе правильно или нет...

Comment: Я понял, спасибо! Насчёт ширины я имел ввиду адаптивность, всё ли будет правильно в этом вопросе?

Comment: Сам подход в задании параметров правилен или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется так правильно ...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 20px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.wraper {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: bisque;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid gold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}

.center {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.text_style {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .content {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<main class="wraper">

  <header class="header text_style">header</header>

  <div class="content">

    <aside class="left text_style item">left</aside>

    <aside class="center text_style item">center</aside>

    <aside class="right text_style item">right</aside>

  </div>

  <footer class="footer text_style">footer</footer>

</main>
```

Comment: и если заметите что в мобильную версию 1 строчкой переделывается

Comment: Да! Спасибо Вам, так видимо правильнее всего!

Comment: @MaxKrutov Отметьте ответ как принятый (зелёная галочка слева от ответа) если он вам помог.

Comment: Да, конечно с радостью!